# Nested class inaccessiable, g++ gives no error while clang does

Tags: c++, g++, clang, language-lawyer

```
template <typename T>
class Foo{
    private:
        class Bar{            
        };
};

template <typename T>
void Fun(const Foo<T> &f){
    Foo<int>::Bar b;  //This line of code.
}

int main(){
    Foo<int> f;
    Fun(f);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ can compile it with no error while Clang points out that `Foo<int>::Bar` is inaccessiable.

g++: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9scQUmfVLQU6IM0J
Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/dQm9VcsZURbjxrFZ

What's wrong with g++? I trusted it so much. Should I use Clang for learning instead?

Comment: `Foo<int>::Bar b;` Looks weird to appear in a generalized template.

Comment: @drescherjm g++ only gives *unused variables* warnings.

Comment: Umm... You can use both?

Comment: Compilers have bugs.  It's just the nature of the game, especially considering how complex the C++ language is.  This's shouldn't force you to change compilers though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Here's the situation. I was writing some code and changed a nested class as `private`. I was thinking the IDE(it uses g++) should gives a error. But it didn't. So I was thinking that I might be wrong. Then I tried on Clang, I felt untrusted on g++.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes.. But I am always told that *remember that compilers are way much smarter than you*. Since I am still learning, so sometimes I memory what the compiler gives me back.

Comment: removing the template on Fun gives the expected error https://wandbox.org/permlink/9scQUmfVLQU6IM0J

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok. Please mark it as duplicated or I can delete it direclty. Maybe next time I shouldn't ask this kind of question. It's not helpful after all.

Comment: I've closed it as a dupe.  If you want to delete it you can.